# What is the interpretation of the Rev 12:1-2 sign

Tags: revelation, prophecy, rapture

On September 23, 2017, it appears that Revelation 12:1-2 was fulfilled:

> 12 A great sign appeared in heaven: a woman clothed with the sun, with the moon under her feet and a crown of twelve stars on her head. 2 She was pregnant and cried out in pain as she was about to give birth.

It occurs only once every 7000 years. It marks the middle of the tribulation as I’ve understood it. However, it does not seem that all of the Scriptures have been fulfilled nor that we are truly past the great tribulation.

[image]

Three wandering planets, mercury Venus and mars, were positioned in Leo which is the sign of the king.  This formed the crown of 12 stars upon the head of Virgo the virgin.  You can see that Virgo is clothed with the sun and the moon is that her feet.

What occurred prior to this is the path of the wandering planet Jupiter.  It traveled through the loins and Gemini which was known also as husband and wife in ancient Israel. The planet went into retrograde through Gemini’s loins. As it traveled through the constellations, it knocked over the bowl of God‘s wrath onto the head of the serpent. It continued to travel through Leo, the sign of the king, and appeared with a blood moon as it entered the womb of Virgo.  From there, Jupiter remained in retrograde in Virgo’s womb for 42 weeks - impregnating the virgin.

We are more than four years past this clear celestial sign. Remember that Revelations 12:1 says “And there appeared a great wonder in heaven” indicating this sign would be fulfilled in the stars.

Please help interpret the timing of end-time events in light of this information.  There are still many scriptures yet to be fulfilled like the rider on the pale horse, the boils on people’s skin, and the rapture.

Comment: Welcome to BH.SE.  Please take the [tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [types of questions that are on topic](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and the [types of questions to avoid](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).  Contemporary applications are off topic, so could you edit the question so it is about the text?

Comment: Where do you get the 7000 year figure from?  According to [Biblical signs in the sky on September 23, 2017? | Astronomy Essentials | EarthSky](https://earthsky.org/human-world/biblical-signs-in-the-sky-september-23-2017/), "*In the past 1,000 years, this same event has happened at least four times already, in 1827, 1483, 1293, and 1056.*".

Comment: Hi Kay, it looks like you are new to the site. You started out with a pretty controversial topic and people often do start with something that has been burning on their minds. End time events are very important in theology and church history. Don't be discouraged by having a question closed. Hermeneutical principles can be applied to this question, but you might try to narrow the focus by not referencing things not found in the passage. Let me know if you need any help. God bless you!

Comment: You’re right that I am new and seeking more information about this topic so I posted for feedback.  I’m doing a broader internet search instead.  This is probably not the right forum.  Thank you and Gos bless!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this verse is just as worthy of hermeneutical interpretation as any other in the Bible. You may want to try to narrow the focus of the question so it doesn't get closed.

One of the reasons people probably react negatively to end times prophecy, especially in Revelation, is that it has been often abused with people making wild-eyed predictions with specific dates that invariably fail, much to the disappointment and even significant harm to those who listened.

This particular passage was taken out of context and used that way over 4 years ago by at least one guy (Scottie?) who got many worked up over the likelihood that Jesus would come on Rosh Hashanah in 2017. He got his few moments of fame.

You have to be careful about looking at the stars to predict the future. When signs really start to happen in the heavens, you won't have to be guessing about what they mean. This is also true about a lot of events predicted in Revelation. As the events occur, it will be obvious to those who have been wise enough to study the book. It will be a great encouragement to the saints in the most incredibly trying time in history.

Revelation 12 has nothing to do with the rapture so do not allow anyone to deceive you with elaborate interpretations of signs in the stars. The purpose of the chapter was to give a background history on Satan's war against Jesus, the man child, and the church. Jesus was taken up to God and to his throne after he completed his work on earth and he will one day "rule all the nations with an iron scepter.” Rev. 12:5

Comment: Very nice, balanced answer.